# How to read a file into a Java Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, file-io, bitmap, arrays

I know how to read a bitmap file into a byte array. How is the byte array then converted to a Java Bitmap?

Comment: also, define bitmap file

Comment: Java Bitmap: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Comment: Bitmap file: the file you get in windows when you do a "Save as .bmp"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `BitmapFactory` if you already have your byte array:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(yourByteArray, offset, length);
```

Answer (score 45):

Skip the byte array if you want:
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);