# How can I set a background image for a button from ..Activity.java, in android?

Tags: android, android-button

I wrote the following code:

```
            ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v;  
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tom);
```

tom.png is in res/drawable. The code above it's working, but I saved the image name in the database (for example "tom"). And I tried the code behind:

```
    InfoDataSource datasourceRuta = new InfoDataSource(this);
    datasourceRuta.open();

    String strInfo = "";        


    List<Info> objInfo = datasourceRuta.GetInfo()

    for (Info info : objInfo) {
        strInfo = info.getImg0();

            ImageButton b = (ImageButton) v;  
                b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.strInfo);  

        }
```

strInfo = "tom", and I get an error: strInfo cannot be resolved or is not a field.
Do you have a solution for me?
Should I save the image in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy "tom" image to drawable folder, Android generates a field in gen/R.java a tom field for that. In this case. There is no strInfo in R.java, so you can't access it.

In this case, you should read from image file, create a Bitmap and setBackground for your button. You can take this for reference: [How to read a file into a Java Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097088/how-to-read-a-file-into-a-java-bitmap)